# login to play developer console from app

Tags: android

I want to make an app that displays the information from play developer console in an easy to read way.

What procedure would be best to use to get an html file that i can scrape the info out of?

Is there a library that can simplify this proccess?

Comment: Apart from your problem, there's already an app in the Play Store that does about the same: [Andlytics](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.github.andlyticsproject)

Comment: afaik it doesnt have a widget + i am just creating apps as proof of concept for myself (broadening my programming skills ;) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm currently trying to do this on a php website I'm developing. So far, I've managed to authenticate through the service, get JSON responses of various statistics, and I'm currently trying to parse them.

If you need some help/guidelines, don't hesitate to ask me a few questions, I'd be glad to help. (I've been inspired by the Andlytics android app github project, in order to do this)

I know you want to do this with Android, but the mains steps are the same. I really advice that you check how Andlytics does it.

Also, I can confirm that there is no library available yet, I've been searching for a while before trying to do my own thing.

Comment: I am looking over the andlytics source code atm, it seems possible to get the stuff i want out of it.                                                            It still seems wrong that a company like Google can't provide an easier access to their services.

Comment: In fact, the developer console as you see it (version 2) has only been officially out since October 2012, so I guess they will someday provide a real API. It could also be because they want to encourage Android developers to put their Analytics plugin in their apps, to have more precise statistics. (it is mentionned that the dev console  is still quite new in its current state, and often lacks of accuracy and even logic, for some numbers. I saw that for the apps on my account, some stats just don't make sense when you put them together)

Comment: How hard would it be for them to make a library available for us where we can make direct code calls for the stats we want.